# GLX is compiled with wrong version (Display resolution and hardware acceleration stopped working)

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, display, nvidia

I have two Ubuntu 14 Desktops (identical). Both were working fine until Friday. 
Some updates appear to have been performed on the non-working machine...

```
2019-03-18 02:29:32 install linux-base:all <keine> 4.5ubuntu1~14.04.1
2019-03-18 02:29:32 install linux-modules-3.13.0-167-generic:amd64 <keine> 3.13.0-167.217
2019-03-18 02:29:33 install linux-image-3.13.0-167-generic:amd64 <keine> 3.13.0-167.217
2019-03-18 02:29:33 install linux-modules-extra-3.13.0-167-generic:amd64 <keine> 3.13.0-167.217
2019-03-18 02:29:36 install linux-image-generic:amd64 <keine> 3.13.0.167.178
2019-03-18 02:29:36 install linux-headers-3.13.0-167:all <keine> 3.13.0-167.217
2019-03-18 02:29:38 install linux-headers-3.13.0-167-generic:amd64 <keine> 3.13.0-167.217
2019-03-18 02:29:39 install linux-headers-generic:amd64 <keine> 3.13.0.167.178
2019-03-18 02:29:39 install linux-generic:amd64 <keine> 3.13.0.167.178
2019-03-18 02:29:39 install linux-modules-4.4.0-143-generic:amd64 <keine> 4.4.0-143.169~14.04.2
2019-03-18 02:29:40 install linux-image-4.4.0-143-generic:amd64 <keine> 4.4.0-143.169~14.04.2
2019-03-18 02:29:40 install linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-143-generic:amd64 <keine> 4.4.0-143.169~14.04.2
2019-03-18 02:29:44 install linux-headers-4.4.0-143:all <keine> 4.4.0-143.169~14.04.2
2019-03-18 02:29:46 install linux-headers-4.4.0-143-generic:amd64 <keine> 4.4.0-143.169~14.04.2
```

Now the display resolution (and apparently the hardware acceleration) are not working on the broken machine. Using `glxgears` shows the following error...

[image]

`lshw` shows the Nvidia card as UNattached (please excuse the German)

```
*-display UNGEFORDERT
     Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller
     Produkt: NVIDIA Corporation
     Hersteller: NVIDIA Corporation
     Physische ID: 0
     Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:01:00.0
     Version: a1
     Breite: 64 bits
     Takt: 33MHz
     Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
     Konfiguration: latency=0
     Ressourcen: memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(Größe=128) memory:df000000-df07ffff
```

And the `/var/log/Xorg.o.log` shows that different GLX modules are being called (`glxserver_nvidia` versus `libglx.so`)...

**Working machine**

```
[ 99380.611] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[ 99380.611] (II) Loading sub module "glxserver_nvidia"
[ 99380.611] (II) LoadModule: "glxserver_nvidia"
[ 99380.611] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglxserver_nvidia.so
[ 99380.633] (II) Module glxserver_nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[ 99380.633]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[ 99380.633]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
```

**NON-WORKING MACHINE**

```
[  1042.464] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[  1042.464] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  1042.465] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  1042.489] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1042.490]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.0.0
[  1042.490]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 9.0
```

I've reinstalled all the original drivers...

```
apt-get --reinstall install nvidia-410 nvidia-410-dev nvidia-modprobe nvidia-opencl-icd-410 nvidia-settings
apt --reinstall install libxcb-glx0 libxcb-glx0-dev
apt install libcudnn5 libcudnn5-dev -y
```

My Google'ing hasn't given me any direction towardsinstalling `glxserver_nvidia`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, if `glxserver_nvidia` is not loaded, it's because the xserver consider the nvidia graphics card is not using (for instance, not connected to a monitor).

I used to face the same problem on my server. I fixed it by using `nvidia-xconfig` to attach virtual monitors to my nvidia graphic cards.